# Stopping Scheduled Push Notification In react native push notifications

Tags: javascript, react-native, push-notification, react-native-push-notification

I want to stop sending my scheduled notifications if I press a button.
Like I want to unschedule / stop /cancel the push notifications which was scheduled earlier and then further Notifications shouldn't come
Using Lib
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-push-notification
My Goal is not cancel notification from notification bar or centre. buT TO Stop this scheduled notification

```
    PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
        channelId: 'channel name',
        date: new Date(Date.now()),
        title: 'title',
        message: 'message',
        repeatType: 'day',

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't verified below code but should work as suggested in plugin github issues page

```
const id = 1;

PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
    id:  `${id}`
    message: 'My Scheduled Notification Message',
    date: new Date(Date.now() + (5 * 1000))
  })

PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications({ id: `${id}` })
```

[Link to issue](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/966#issuecomment-599561893)

Comment: This will clear the notification from notification bar only ryt?

Comment: No it will cancel scheduled as well but you need to manage id for that, if you want to remove all scheduled notification then use `PushNotification.cancelAllLocalNotifications()`